# Can I specify a custom Dockerfile name with Heroku container:push?

Tags: docker, heroku, heroku-cli

I have a project with two Dockerfiles in the same directory:

```
project
  /Dockerfile.web
  /Dockerfile.worker
```

I can use them to build different parts of the same project very easily with `docker-compose`. However, I struggle to tell `heroku container:push` that I want to use a custom Dockerfile. It seems I can only refer to custom directories to build.

Is there a solution to that?

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to my question.

There doesn't seem to be a way to specify a custom Dockerfile name to `heroku container:push`.

However, as per [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-container-push) there is `--recursive` parameter for the `heroku container:push` command that does exactly what I needed:

Look for **Dockerfile.web** and build the **web** dyno:

```
heroku container:push web --recursive
```

Look for **Dockerfile.worker** and build the **worker** dyno:

```
heroku container:push worker --recursive
```

Look for both **Dockerfile.web** and **Dockerfile.worker** and build both dynos:

```
heroku container:push web worker --recursive
```